# division by sum of exponentials of large negative numbers

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation, exponential-function

I need to evaluate the following numerically:

$$ 
f = \frac{\exp(a)}{\exp(a)+\exp(b)+\exp(c) + \exp(d)}
$$

$a,b,c$ and $d$ are large negative numbers, they are smaller than -1000. Numerically exp(-1000) is equal to zero. Directly evaluating this expression would thus lead to a numerator and a denominator equal to zero.

How can I evaluate this expression?

Comment: $f = \frac{1}{1+\exp(b-a)+\exp(c-a) + \exp(d-a)}$

Answer (score 1):

As @d.k.o.'s comment hints at, your expression is:
$$
\frac{1}{1 + \exp(b - a) + exp(c - a) + \exp(d - a)}
$$
If the resulting $b - a$, $c - a$, $d - a$ are still (very) negative (small exponentials), a few terms of the geometric series should be accurate enough. If some turn out positive, call them $A$, $B$, $C$ in order of decreasing value:
$$
\frac{1}{1 + \exp(A) + \exp(B) + \exp(C)}
  = \frac{1}{\exp(A) (1 + \exp(B - A) + \exp(C - A) + \exp(-A))} 
$$
and this should work out better numerically.